Logscale tick marks not showing up consistently in matplotlib python
I am plotting ax1 and ax2 in semilogy, however only ax2 shows the logy tickmarks even though the generating code for both is the same. I have tried using ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.LogLocator(base=10.0, numticks=15)) but still it doesn't do the expected behaviour and I would like it to be automatic.
def plot_optimization_results(history):
    """
    Plot the optimization results
    """
    iterations = [h['iteration'] for h in history]
    f_values = [h['f'] for h in history]
    F_norms = [h['grad_norm'] for h in history]
    x_values = np.array([h['x'] for h in history])
    
    # Create figure with subplots
    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
    
    # Plot merit function value
    ax1.semilogy(iterations, f_values)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(5))
    ax1.set_xlabel('Iteration')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Merit Function Value')
    ax1.set_title('Convergence of Merit Function')
    ax1.grid(True)
    
    # Plot norm of F(x)
    ax2.semilogy(iterations, F_norms)
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(5))
    ax2.set_xlabel('Iteration')
    ax2.set_ylabel('||F(x)||')
    ax2.set_title('Norm of F(x) vs Iteration')
    ax2.grid(True)

    ...
    return fig



You might have noticed that the range of y values is much larger in your ax1 (which span roughly 14 orders of magnitude) as compared to ax2 (which span only roughly 8), which is why (1) not all major tick marks are shown (only the ones with even exponents) and (2) the minor tick marks, which you call logy tickmarks, are suppressed in the former. This is because Matplotlib chooses to suppress some tick marks there to avoid visual clutter.
Following the answers to this related question, we can

enforce all major tick marks to show by setting their numticks value (i.e. their allowed maximum number) to a very high number,
enforce all minor tick marks to show by, again, setting their numticks value to a very high number and, additionally, explicitly specifying their tick intervals.

This could look as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
# Create some dummy data in the necessary range
vals = np.logspace(-13, 1)

# Use default formatting: won't show all major ticks, won't show minor ticks
ax1.semilogy(vals)
ax1.set_title("default")

ax2.semilogy(vals)
# Enforce all major ticks
ax2.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(numticks=np.inf)
ax2.set_title("all major ticks")

ax3.semilogy(vals)
# Enforce all major ticks
ax3.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(numticks=np.inf)
# Enforce and set minor ticks
ax3.yaxis.get_minor_locator().set_params(numticks=np.inf, subs=range(1, 10))
ax3.set_title("all major ticks + minor ticks")

Which would produce (using Matplotlib 3.9.2):

I know you said you wanted this to be automatic, but I am not sure if there is a more automated way. What you could do to increase automation is wrapping all necessary steps into a helper function that you can then apply to all of your plots.
So, for instance, we could define:
def semilogy(ax, *args, **kwargs):
    ax.semilogy(*args, **kwargs)
    # Enforce all major ticks
    ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(numticks=np.inf)
    # Enforce and set minor ticks
    ax.yaxis.get_minor_locator().set_params(numticks=np.inf, subs=range(1, 10))

And then write:
semilogy(ax3, vals)

